# Is there a way to search for questions with no question marks in the title?

Tags: support, search

On at least one SE site, I've found that a relatively good barometer for a bad question (one that either needs heavy editing, or closure) is if it lacks a question mark in its title. To that end, I wanted to search for such questions, but the query `is:question title:-"?"` doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to find out what questions have no question marks in their titles?

Comment: Just a supplementary info in case you're not aware: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152439/should-questions-have-question-marks-at-the-end-of-the-subject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find how to do it with the advanced search (probably it's really impossible), but stumbled into [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/274814/question-titles-without-question-marks) on data explorer. It seems to search for the questions you want.

Comment: FWIW, I also just found a query for [question titles that aren't phrased as questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/291152/find-questions-titles-that-are-not-phrased-as-questions). I think it's even more useful for what I wanted to do.